# How to derive (∃x)(y)(Ax ⊃ By) from (x)Ax ⊃ (y)By?

Tags: logic

[image]

Upon multiple attempts, I keep arriving at the same conclusion, but I believe this is not right. How shall one proceed with this one? I've exhausted the resources I have at my reach.

Comment: Does the goal involve Dx => Cy or Ax => By?

Comment: @FrankHubeny ops, I fixed it now. Now it's the problem I have in hand.

Comment: I end up with 8. (∃x)[Ax ⊃ (y)By] 7 EG, but that's not quite right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Premise : (x)Ax → (y)By

1) assume Ax --- [a]

2) Assume ¬Ax --- [b]

3) assume  ¬[(∃x)(y)(Ax → By)] --- [c]

4) ⊥ --- contradiction : from 1) and 2)

5) By --- from 4) by [Ex falso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion#Symbolic_representation)

6) Ax → By --- from 1) and 5) by →-intro, discharging [a]

7) (y)(Ax → By) --- from 6) by [UG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization)

8) (∃x)(y)(Ax → By) --- from 7) by [EG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization)

9) ⊥ --- contradiction : from 3) and 8)

10) Ax --- from 2) and 9) by [Double Negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation), discharging [b]

11) (x)Ax --- from 10) by UG (no open assumptuions with x free)

12) (y)By --- from Premise and 11) by →-elim

13) By --- from 12) by [UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation)

14) Ax → By --- from 13) by →-intro

15) (y)(Ax → By) --- from 14) by UG

16) (∃x)(y)(Ax → By) --- from 15) by EG

17) ⊥ --- contradiction : from 3) and 16)

> 18) (∃x)(y)(Ax → By) --- from 3) and 17) by DN, discharging [a].

Answer (score 1):

This is [Mauro ALLEGRANZA's answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/56304/29944) formatted using Klement's proof checker. Since "A" is used to code the universal quantifier in this software I replaced name "A" with "P" and, to hopefully avoid confusion, "B" with "Q".

[image]

Here is a description of the rules: contradiction introduction (⊥I), explosion (X), conditional introduction (→I), universal introduction (∀I), existential introduction (∃I), negation introduction (¬I), double negation elimination (DNE), conditional elimination (→E), universal elimination (∀E), and indirect proof (IP).

---

Reference

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/